# What can i do, if Add-Migration doesnt work?

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, winui-3

I have a project with a Data Directory what contains the Directories "Context" and "Entities". In the project level i tried out "Add-Migration Initial". I'm getting there a "Build started" and a "Build succeeded". But i haven't a Migrations Directory with the Migrations. What can happend?

Comment: Adding `-Verbose` may give more hints as to why it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

statement add-migration has a switch to specify out put directory.
it maybe has diffrence with your out put directory for do it use "add-migration [-OutputDir ]" with your address of your out put dictionary

For technical information, type: "get-help Add-Migration -full".